# .net core 3.1 c# cors not working with angular 7

Tags: c#, .net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

hi i have tried different ways to enable cors but failed my code is.am using spa app for presenting data but couldn't pass cors.browser shows the error Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/Values. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
        {
            opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x =>
        {
            x.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
            x.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });
        IdentityBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>(opt =>
        {opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;            
        }).AddRoles<IdentityRole>();
        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
        builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>();
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII
                        .GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false

                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) == false)
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(constant.RequireVisionTrackAdminRole, policy => policy.RequireRole(constant.VisionTrackAdmin));
            options.AddPolicy(constant.RequireAdminRole, policy => policy.RequireRole(constant.Admin, constant.VisionTrackAdmin));
        });
        services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(VisionTrackRepository).Assembly);
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
    }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }       
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();          
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(
            options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
        );
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<VisionTrackHub>("/VisionTrack").RequireCors("CorsPolicy");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}").RequireCors("CorsPolicy");

        });
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });

    }
```

also tried this guide not working [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1]
Is it because of authorization middle ware or is something to be done on endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Startup` file you have two main method, `ConfigureServices`, and `Configure` method.

In you `ConfigureServices` method define it as below:

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                                  .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
```

And in `Configure` method add this line:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

**Note:** `app.UseCors("CorsPolicy")` should be after `app.UseRouting()` and before `app.UserAuthentication()`

Answer (score 3):

I think that's related to fact, that [you cannot use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Credentialed_requests_and_wildcards) both `options.AllowAnyOrigin()` and authentication middleware. In your case you are obliged to explicitly define allowed origins.

If you defined your CORS in a way given below, the request block should not happen.

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder
        .WithOrigins(new[]{"http://YOUR_FRONTEND_ORIGIN"})
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials();
}));
```

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Comment: What for local? I.e. I'd use "https://example.com" as the origin paired with `AllowCredentials`, but how do I also `AllowAnyOrigin` for when I'm running on my dev machine?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved comment line //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

```
        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();           

        app.UseRouting();


        // global cors policy
        app.UseCors();


        app.UseAuthorization();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution solved my case:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddCors();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(
            options => options.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => _ = true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()
        );

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16672